# vuetable-2 - How to fetch data into table in laravel/vuejs usig API

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, vue-tables-2

I am trying  implementing vuetable-2 in laravel/ vuejs but I don't know how to pass data to the table from api , in sample table we do it like below.

Any help please

> methods: {loadBooks() {   axios.get("api/Book").then(({ data }) =>
>   (this.Books = data));  }
>       mounted() { this.loadBooks();  },

```
> <tr v-for="Book in Books.data" v-bind:key="Book.id"> <td>{{ Book.name
> }}</td></tr>
```

here the full code of Book.vue

```
    <template>
    <div id="app">
        <filter-bar></filter-bar>
        <vuetable
            ref="vuetable"
            api-url="http://vuetable.ratiw.net/api/users"
            :fields="fields"
            pagination-path=""
            :css="css.table"
            :sort-order="sortOrder"
            :multi-sort="true"
            detail-row-component="my-detail-row"
            :append-params="moreParams"
            @vuetable:cell-clicked="onCellClicked"
            @vuetable:pagination-data="onPaginationData"
        ></vuetable>
        <div class="vuetable-pagination">
            <vuetable-pagination-info
                ref="paginationInfo"
                info-class="pagination-info"
            ></vuetable-pagination-info>
            <vuetable-pagination
                ref="pagination"
                :css="css.pagination"
                @vuetable-pagination:change-page="onChangePage"
            ></vuetable-pagination>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import accounting from "accounting";
import moment from "moment";
import Vuetable from "vuetable-2/src/components/Vuetable";
import VuetablePagination from "vuetable-2/src/components/VuetablePagination";
import VuetablePaginationInfo from "vuetable-2/src/components/VuetablePaginationInfo";
import Vue from "vue";
import VueEvents from "vue-events";
import CustomActions from "./CustomActions";
import DetailRow from "./DetailRow";
import FilterBar from "./FilterBar";
Vue.use(VueEvents);
Vue.component("custom-actions", CustomActions);
Vue.component("my-detail-row", DetailRow);
Vue.component("filter-bar", FilterBar);
export default {
    components: {
        Vuetable,
        VuetablePagination,
        VuetablePaginationInfo
    },
    data() {
        return {
            Books: {},
            getAllBook: {},
            fields: [
                {
                    name: "__sequence",
                    title: "#",
                    titleClass: "text-right",
                    dataClass: "text-right"
                },
                {
                    name: "__checkbox",
                    titleClass: "text-center",
                    dataClass: "text-center"
                },
                {
                    name: "نوم",
                    sortField: "نوم"
                },
                {
                    name: "ایمل",
                    sortField: "ایمل"
                },
                {
                    name: "birthdate",
                    sortField: "birthdate",
                    titleClass: "text-center",
                    dataClass: "text-center",
                    callback: "formatDate|DD-MM-YYYY"
                },
                {
                    name: "nickname",
                    sortField: "nickname",
                    callback: "allcap"
                },
                {
                    name: "gender",
                    sortField: "gender",
                    titleClass: "text-center",
                    dataClass: "text-center",
                    callback: "genderLabel"
                },
                {
                    name: "salary",
                    sortField: "salary",
                    titleClass: "text-center",
                    dataClass: "text-right",
                    callback: "formatNumber"
                },
                {
                    name: "__component:custom-actions",
                    title: "Actions",
                    titleClass: "text-center",
                    dataClass: "text-center"
                }
            ],
            data: [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    name: "xxxxxxxxx",
                    nickname: "xxxxxxx",
                    email: "xxx@xxx.xxx",
                    birthdate: "xxxx-xx-xx",
                    gender: "X",
                    group_id: 1
                },
                {
                    id: 50,
                    name: "xxxxxxxxx",
                    nickname: "xxxxxxx",
                    email: "xxx@xxx.xxx",
                    birthdate: "xxxx-xx-xx",
                    gender: "X",
                    group_id: 3
                }
            ],
            css: {
                table: {
                    tableClass:
                        "table table-bordered table-striped table-hover",
                    ascendingIcon: "glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up",
                    descendingIcon: "glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"
                },
                pagination: {
                    wrapperClass: "pagination",
                    activeClass: "active",
                    disabledClass: "disabled",
                    pageClass: "page",
                    linkClass: "link",
                    icons: {
                        first: "",
                        prev: "",
                        next: "",
                        last: ""
                    }
                },
                icons: {
                    first: "glyphicon glyphicon-step-backward",
                    prev: "glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left",
                    next: "glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right",
                    last: "glyphicon glyphicon-step-forward"
                }
            },
            sortOrder: [
                { field: "email", sortField: "email", direction: "asc" }
            ],
            moreParams: {}
        };
    },
    methods: {
        loadBooks() {
            axios.get("api/Book").then(({ data }) => (this.Books = data));
            axios
                .get("api/getAllBook")
                .then(({ data }) => (this.getAllBook = data));
        },
        allcap(value) {
            return value.toUpperCase();
        },
        genderLabel(value) {
            return value === "M"
                ? '<span class="label label-success"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i> Male</span>'
                : '<span class="label label-danger"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></i> Female</span>';
        },
        formatNumber(value) {
            return accounting.formatNumber(value, 2);
        },
        formatDate(value, fmt = "D MMM YYYY") {
            return value == null ? "" : moment(value, "YYYY-MM-DD").format(fmt);
        },
        onPaginationData(paginationData) {
            this.$refs.pagination.setPaginationData(paginationData);
            this.$refs.paginationInfo.setPaginationData(paginationData);
        },
        onChangePage(page) {
            this.$refs.vuetable.changePage(page);
        },
        onCellClicked(data, field, event) {
            console.log("cellClicked: ", field.name);
            this.$refs.vuetable.toggleDetailRow(data.id);
        }
    },
    events: {
        "filter-set"(filterText) {
            this.moreParams = {
                filter: filterText
            };
            Vue.nextTick(() => this.$refs.vuetable.refresh());
        },
        "filter-reset"() {
            this.moreParams = {};
            Vue.nextTick(() => this.$refs.vuetable.refresh());
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.loadBooks();
    },
    created() {
        this.loadBooks();

    }
};
</script>
<style>
.pagination {
    margin: 0;
    float: right;
}
.pagination a.page {
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    margin-right: 2px;
}
.pagination a.page.active {
    color: white;
    background-color: #337ab7;
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    margin-right: 2px;
}
.pagination a.btn-nav {
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 5px 7px;
    margin-right: 2px;
}
.pagination a.btn-nav.disabled {
    color: lightgray;
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 5px 7px;
    margin-right: 2px;
    cursor: not-allowed;
}
.pagination-info {
    float: left;
}
</style>
```

Comment: DId you read about data-path? https://www.vuetable.com/guide/json-data-format.html, you need to add to vuetable :data-path="Books.data" (is waiting an Array)

Comment: it gives me this error [Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "dataPath". Expected String with value "[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]", got Array

Comment: Your problem is that your array contain array of object and not objects in fact. Put a sample of your Books contain to give you better solution :-)